# Flutter how to add doc id with data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I ma just entering my data in Firestore. I need to know how can I put my doc id in data?

My simple code

```
              _firestore.collection('Users').add({
                'shopname': 'Aam Dukaan',
                'number': '9232313131',
                'lastupdate': '',
                'sendQty': '',
                'id': 'here i need doc id '
              });
```

More explanation

[image]

From image you can see I need this document id in my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
String id = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc().id;
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(id).set({
                'shopname': 'Aam Dukaan',
                'number': '9232313131',
                'lastupdate': '',
                'sendQty': '',
                'id': id,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ID before you create the new document with `add` and use `set` instead of `add`:

```dart
final document = _firestore.collection('Users').doc();

 _firestore.collection('Users').doc(document.id).set({
                'shopname': 'Aam Dukaan',
                'number': '9232313131',
                'lastupdate': '',
                'sendQty': '',
                'id': 'here i need doc id '
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a document with desired id.

```
final usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");
String id = "123"; 
    usersRef.doc(id).set(
        {
          "name":"somename" ,
          "id":"$id",

        }
```